# postgres case statement with subquery

Tags: postgresql, join, case

I have a subquery like this

```
with subquery as (select host from table_A where << some condition >>)
```

and in my main query, I am querying data from another table called table_B, and one of the columns is called destination_host. Now I need to check if the destination_host is in the list returned from my subquery, then I want to output TypeA in my select statement or else TypeB. My select statement looks something like

```
select name, place, destination_host
from table_B 
where <<some condition>>
```

I want to output a fourth column that is based on a condition check, let's say we call this host_category and if the destination_host value exists in the subquery then I want to add value typeA or else typeB. Please can you help me understand how to write this. I understand that it is hard to provide guidance if you don't have actual data to work with.

I tried using case statements such as this one:

```
when (destination_host in (select host from subquery)) THEN 'typeA' 
when (destination_host not in (select host from subquery)) THEN 'typeB' 
end as host_category
```

but I don't think this is the way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `EXISTS`:

```
WITH subquery AS (...)
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subquery
                         WHERE subquery.host = table_b.destination_host)
            THEN 'typeA'
            ELSE 'typeB'
       END
FROM table_b;
```

With queries like that, you have to take care of NULL values. If `table_b.destination_host` is NULL, the row will always show up as `typeB`, because `NULL = NULL` is not `TRUE` in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, I will give this a try and let you know how I go